# Destroying instatiated objects in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have 2 different scripts attached to 2 different game objects.

One instantiates a bunch of game obejcts and I want the second one to destroy them.

```
code1: 

    public static volatile GameObject newObj;
    public GameObject go;

    newObj = GameObject.Instantiate(go);
    newObj.tag = "mytag";



Code 2:
      GameObject[] all_cloned_prefabs = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("mytag");

        foreach (var AllPrefabs in all_cloned_prefabs)
        {
            Destroy(AllPrefabs);
        }
```

When I run code 2 (let's say by pressing a button on GUI, it doesn't destroy the objects I created on the screen.What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are sure these objects get created properly? Do you gert any exceptions? Is the first script even being called to begin with? It's difficult to tell what's wrong with only a few lines of code and little to no context.

Comment: What's with the volatile keyword there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I put all the objects inside a list, made the list `public static volatile prefab1`. accessed it from second script. then destroyed them 
It worked perfect.

```
   foreach (GameObject obj1 in script1.prefab1)
    {
        Destroy(obj1);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to understand what you are trying to do in the first code with `public static volatile GameObject newObj;`, it's not used in the other part of the code you shown.

The second code looks fine, what could be wrong is:

- The objects you want to destroy are inactive (`FindGameObjectsWithTag` will not return inactive GameObjects).
- You didn't created the tag "mytag" in the [Tag Manager](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-TagManager.html).

Try to [Debug.Log](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Debug.Log.html) the content of the `all_cloned_prefabs` array to see if it actually contains anything.

Comment: I initially had that as static volatile so I could access it from the other script and go straight up: Destroy(code1. newObj) and that didn't work

Comment: I don't know the specifics of your implementation but that sounds like a bad idea. If you want to track a set of GameObjects have an other script hold a list (array) of those GameObjects.


Also, did you manage to fix your issue?